# How to replace all elements of a list using a for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

Question
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CbX7L.png]

The question here asks to make two lists/arrays in python and fill it with 0s initially and then occupy them with the relevant values.

```
import numpy as np
x = []
y = []

for i in range (0,101):
    x.append(0)
    y.append(0)

xx = np.linspace(1,10,101)
print(xx)

for a in range (len(y)):
    for j in xx:
        fx = np.log(j)
        y[a] = fx

for b in range (len(x)):
    for k in xx:
        x[b] = k

print(x)
print(" ")
print(y)
```

I used a nested for loop to traverse through the values in the xx list and used the log function and stored the values in a variable and then replace the 0s in the (y)list with the function values over each iteration. Same thing with the x list but just replace the 0s with the value of the variable which is used in the function respectively.
However the output I keep getting is not right and I can't get what is going wrong within the loops. The output should show the values of x in the first list and the values of f(x) in the second list however it only shows the value of the last x in the range as well as the value of the last f(x) in the range.

Output
[image]

Comment: Please limit your example size, then copy-paste the output (and some expected output) as code into your question; *not* as an image.

Comment: "it only shows the value of the last x": double check your nested loop, and think about what it does: `a` only increases when the inner loop is done, so `y[a]` gets continuously overwritten in the inner loop. Hence you always end up with the last value of `fx` for inner loop.

Comment: I haven't fully read/understood what you precisely want to achieve, but I'm sure this can be done without any loops, with normal NumPy vector-wise assignments. Please read the NumPy guide to learn about that usage. With NumPy, try and avoid for loops as much as reasonably possible. (There are for loops, but these are hidden under the hood and coded in C.)

Comment: Note that `np.log(xx)` may be of help (removing a loop that way). Or `np.logspace`. And if you do want a two dimensional array/list, consider `np.repeat` or `np.tile`.

Comment: When you want to iterate two iterables at the same time don't nest them, use [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip)

Comment: The main question is: what output do you want: a list of arrays, all containing the same array (that would be what you're currently seem to be trying for). Or simply a 1D array of the logarithm of the result of `linspace`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing you are supposed to use linspace, and enumerate:

```
import numpy as np
size = 101
x = np.zeros(size)
y = np.zeros(size)

for i, n in enumerate(np.linspace(1,10,size)):
    x[i] = n
    y[i] = np.log(n)
```